# Multiple editable content on page

Tags: cms

---

EDIT: I've found out that by using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) I can edit multiple fields on a page. Why WP doesn't have this feature by default I'll never know.

This is the kind of ability I was looking for that PerchCMS has by default.

Thanks for your answers.

---

I'm new to writing websites using Wordpress as a CMS, and in the past I've used a CMS called PerchCMS which allows me to add extra multiple sections by using the php tag of:

```
<?php perch_content('InformationTitle');?>
<?php perch_content('Information');?>
<?php perch_content('AboutTitle');?>
<?php perch_content('AboutContent');?>
```

With Wordpress I really don't understand how to add multiple sections in this way, I trawled the Internet for answers, but there appear to be no answers anywhere else.

Part of my code is as follows:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/logo.png" class="fg3 logo" alt="Logo" />


          <div id='services'>
            <p>
              <?php the_content('services'); ?>
            </p>
          </div>

           <div id='about'>
            <p>
              <?php the_content('about'); ?>
            </p>
          </div>
```

With this method, all the content I write gets repeated.

What am I doing wrong? I understand that the loop is there to loop through the posts on the page, and I've seen mention of plugins such to achieve this, but surely Wordpress should offer this by default? There are many many sites that have different sections that need to be edited independently.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a page that's editable from the front end, or from the admin screens?  You can accomplish what you're looking for in the back end, using [meta boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and [`wp_editor()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor). I don't have time to write a complete answer right now, but I'll try to come up with something later today, if no one else has.

Comment: A page that is editable from the back end, are meta boxes similar to what I've been doing with PerchCMS?

Comment: I haven't used PerchCMS, so I can't say for sure.  Meta boxes allow you to add extra (meta) information to a post/page/custom post type.  Then, in the front end, you would pull the meta information out using [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) for display.  Essentially, the post's content would be your first section, and then the meta boxes would contain your additional fields.

Comment: I really think this is being over complicated, as an example of what I want - http://examples.getbootstrap.com/jumbotron/index.html imagine each section under the heading is what I tried to modify using the_content(). How would you use wordpress to achieve this? Assuming of course that they're NOT links to other pages, just blocks of text.

Comment: In your Bootstrap example, I'm doing something very much like that, but I'm using meta boxes to add the different content areas.  Bear in mind that you're trying to make WordPress -- which ships with a single content area, but the ability to add more using meta boxes -- into a clone of PerchCMS, with multiple editable content areas.  It can be done, but it's going to take some work.

Comment: See this is what I'm a bit afraid of, as far as I'm aware Wordpress is a single post, blog platform. Converted somewhat into a CMS with some kind of community input. I'm starting to think this isn't possible.

Comment: I did a quick Google search for `wordpress multiple content areas`.  Is this -- http://wpmu.org/create-a-more-flexible-cms-with-wordpress-using-multiple-editable-content-blocks/ -- what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass nothing inside `the_content();` except a "read more". 
To achieve what you need it could be done this way;

```
<?php get_header(); ?> // getting the header 

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> // the loop stuff

<?php 
        // PAGE 1
        $page_id = 8454; // id of the page you need to pull out the content of
        $page_data = get_page( $page_id ); // getting the data from the page
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); // filtering

        echo $content; // outputting the content 

        // PAGE 2
        $page_id = 8456;
        $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);

        echo $content;

        // PAGE 3
        $page_id = 8458;
        $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);

        echo $content;

?>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?> <?php // ending while and if ?>

<?php // get_sidebar(); ?> <?php // get the side bar if you want ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?> <?php // the footer ?>
```

• Now create a page (Pages > Add New) with the info you want to output and save it.

• Find out the ID of the page (look at the URL of the page you just saved) it's the number you see after **post.php?=** 
`http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=8458&action=edit`

• Now copy that number and place it $page_id = **HERE**

------- EDITS -------

for me that's the best way... you have lots of pages but at least they are organized. 
BUT!!! if you wish, You can have everything in 1 single page, in admin area, and output only the content of that page. In wordpress you can use HTML tags in pages, so on that single page you can have multiple `<div>s <p>s <h1>s <img>s` with the content you want.

index.php

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 
        $page_id = 8454;
        $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 

        echo $content;
?>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?> <?php // ending while and if ?>

<?php // get_sidebar(); ?> <?php // get the side bar if you want ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?> <?php // the footer ?>
```

in admin are create a page and put all your content inside it:

```
<h1>Services</h1>
<div id="services">CONTENT OF SERVICES</div>

<h1>About</h1>
<div id="about">CONTENT OF About</div>

<h1>Images</h1>
<div id="images">
<img src="" alt="" />
<p>Some description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The trouble is that the content is all on the same page, just in different divs. It's all on the index page of the website.

Comment: in fact. from what I've understood you need the content to be editable from the back end. if so you can create 2 pages, in the back end, with the services information, another one with about information.. and with the code above that you're going to paste into your index.php you can display the content of those pages. And they are also editable from the admin area.

Comment: two pages from admin area into one page on front page

Comment: Surely that's not the only way to have multiple sections of editable content? I've got about 9 pages on this website, each with between 2 and 4 sections to be edited. I'm going to end up with hundreds of extra pages?

Comment: check my EDITS in post above!

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort on this, you've been a great help with your code examples. I really don't understand why people use Wordpress as a CMS, it's so convoluted - the solutions just don't seem user friendly at all!

Comment: no probs. 
Wordpress is for blogs, it does its job more than good. What you need here has not much to do with blog posts, so you have to adapt it a bit. but it's not a big deal as you can see its few lines of simple php code. codex.wordpress.org is very useful!!

Comment: p.s please if you do not have other questions and my answer helped you. accept my answer, so it can be assigned as resolved.